# Save plot to png with Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have just started with Octave and I'm trying to plot something to a png. The plot appears correctly on the screen when I run the script, but the output of the png is completely black. Here's a MWE:

```
clear all
kym=1:10
pcs=1:10
aux=figure();
plot(kym,pcs,'k-')
fname = 'mwe.png';
saveas(aux, fname, 'png');
```

This code outputs the following png:
[image]

Which is obviously not correct. There is also a warning output when running the code:

```
warning: print.m: fig2dev binary is not available.
Some output formats are not available.
warning: called from
    __print_parse_opts__ at line 385 column 9
    print at line 291 column 8
    saveas at line 105 column 3
    mwe at line 7 column 1
```

Google was of little help with this one. Any ideas?

I'm using octave version 4.0.0 on a Linux Mint 18.

Comment: any reason you use gnuplot as graphics_toolkit and not the OpenGL based?

Comment: Not at all. This is just what appeared first for me when I installed it. Like I said, I'm very new to octave. This is my first script literally. Should I change?

Comment: update : this bug is Fixed in 5.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug with Gnuplot 5 http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42838 try to downgrade it to 4.6.5

Comment: I did, and this did work, but now I have another plotting issue. This one is harder to reproduce